# Can't split a property into an array: org.springframework.expression.ParseException

Tags: java, spring

I have problem with SpEL. I'm trying to split a property string into an array using a custom delimiter, but it throws an exception. What's the problem here?

```java
@Component
@Qualifier("propertySourceBased")
public class PropertySourceWisdomProvider implements WisdomProvider {
    @Value("#{'${wisdoms}'.split('|')}")
    private String[] wisdoms;
```

```
wisdoms = Tomorrow is often the busiest day of the week|\
          I have always wanted to be somebody, but I see now I should have been more specific|\
          Knowledge is like underwear. It is useful to have it, but not necessary to show it off|\
          Go to Heaven for the climate, Hell for the company|\
          Going to church doesn't make you a Christian any more than going to a garage makes you an automobile
```

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.ParseException: Expression [#{'Tomorrow is often the busiest day of the week|I have always wanted to be somebody, but I see now I should have been more specific|Knowledge is like underwear. It is useful to have it, but not necessary to show it off|Go to Heaven for the climate, Hell for the company|Going to church doesn't make you a Christian any more than going to a garage makes you an automobile'.split('|')}] @381: Found non terminating string literal starting at position 381
```

It's not a Boot application. The `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` is registered with Spring:

```java
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the apostrophe in "doesn't" is the source of your trouble. Replace it first in string and then apply the split method. If you need any values then convert it back. Use a remarkable  chain of letters or signs for an easy restoring.

Comment: @Reporter What do I replace it with? Spring doesn't provide great support for character escaping

Comment: Can you edit the value before it is being stored into property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Escape the apostrophe with another apostrophe (so that Spring doesn't freak out thinking it's a string that starts but never ends)
2. Escape the pipe character in the SpEL expression with a couple of backslashes: one backslash for regex (`|` is used in regex as "or"), one for Java (it's used to things like `\n` or `\t` and won't recognize `\|`)

```java
    @Value("#{'${wisdoms}'.split('\\|')}")
    private String[] wisdoms;
```

```
wisdoms = Tomorrow is often the busiest day of the week|\
          I have always wanted to be somebody, but I see now I should have been more specific|\
          Knowledge is like underwear. It is useful to have it, but not necessary to show it off|\
          Go to Heaven for the climate, Hell for the company|\
          Going to church doesn''t make you a Christian any more than going to a garage makes you an automobile
```